# How many threads can simultaneously invoke an unsynchronized method of an object?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization

So let's say I have a class X with a method m. Method m is *NOT* synchronized and it doesn't need to be since it doesn't really change the state of the object x of type X.

In some threads I call the method like this: x.m(). All these threads use the same object x.

By how many threads can be this method (method m) called on object x simultaneously? 
Can be the fact that the method is called by, let's say, 100 threads a bottleneck for my application?

thanks.

Comment: I think it depends upon the JVM implementation and possibly the underlying OS

Comment: @awoodland -- I can't think of any circumstance where the JVM or OS would care, other than the standard limitations on how many threads can exist and simultaneously operate at all.

Comment: The JVM might, quite legitimately not map all of the Java threads onto "real" threads at any given point in time.

Comment: Short answer: All of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other's have answered your direct question.

I'd like to clear up something that is *could be* a misconception on your part ... and if it is, it is a **dangerous** one.

> Method m is NOT synchronized and it doesn't need to be since it doesn't really change the state of the object x of type X.

That is not a sufficient condition.  Methods that don't change state typically need to be synchronized too.

Suppose that you have a class Test with a simple getter and setter:

```
public class Test {
    private int foo;

    public int getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }

    public synchronized void setFoo(int foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }
}
```

Is the getter thread-safe?

- According to your rule, yes.
- In reality, no.

Why?  Because unless the threads that call `getFoo` and `setFoo` synchronize properly, a call to `getFoo()` after a call to `setFoo(...)` may see a stale value for `foo`.

This is one of those nasty cases where you will get away with it nearly all of the time.  But very occasionally, the timing of the two calls will be such that the bug bites you.  This kind of bug is likely to slip through the cracks of your testing, and be very difficult to reproduce when it occurs in production.

---

The only case where it *absolutely* safe to access an object's state from multiple threads without synchronizing is when the state is declared as `final`, AND the constructor doesn't publish the object.

Comment: +1 for the getter setter example. Indeed, "synchronized" means that no other *synchronized* methods execute in the same. But, in my case the method just does some processing of the input bytes it receives, so I think it's still safe.

Comment: @ovdsm - are you saying that it doesn't make **any** use of the state of the object?  If so, it should be safe.  Otherwise ...

Comment: This is how I see it now (haven't coded this yet). Actually, it could be a static method then. I think it would be better

Comment: A method doesn't need to be synchronized if it doesn't make any use of any object's state.  It also doesn't need to be synchronized if it uses object state that's "effectively final", though there are a lot of angels dancing on the head of that pin.  And, of course, there's no need to synchronize if the object in question is only used within the current thread.  (Eg, note the difference between Hashtable and HashMap.)

Comment: @Daniel R Hicks - the problem is that "effectively final" leads to a circular argument.  (Q: what is "effectively final"?  A: "final enough" that synchronization is not needed.)  You can't build 100% reliable software based that kind of reasoning ...

Comment: Like I said, a lot of angels.  But there are cases where one can be 100% confident in the correctness, even though the referencing method is not synchronized.  You have to understand the synchronization rules.

Answer (score 3):

If you have more threads in the runnable state than you have physical cores, you'll end up wasting time by context switching... but that's about it. The fact that those threads are executing the same method is irrelevant if there's no coordination between them.

Comment: So, actually the context switching is a kind of a bottleneck in this case. Maybe not a bottleneck, but still not perfect at all. Thanks

Comment: @ovdsrn: Potentially. It depends - if most of the threads are IO-bound (e.g. this method is fetching something from the web) then it's unlikely to be a problem. But the main point is that it isn't "multiple threads *calling the same method*" which is the bottleneck.

Answer (score 1):

Remember the difference between threads and instances. One is executing the other is data. If the data is not under some locking mechanism, or some  resource constraints then the access is only limited by the number of threads that can run by the underlying infrastructure. This is a system (jvm implementation + OS + machine) limitation.

Comment: +1, "system limitation" is what I was getting at with my comment.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, an unsynchronized method doesn't "care" how many threads are invoking it.  It's a purely passive entity and nothing special occurs when a new thread enters it.

Perhaps one thing that confuses some people is the "auto" storage used by a method.  This storage is allocated on the thread's stack, and does not require the active participation of the method.  The method's code is simply given a pointer to the storage.

(Many, many moons ago, it wasn't thus.  Either the "auto" storage was allocated from heap when the method was called, or the method maintained a list of "auto" storage areas.  But that paradigm disappeared maybe 40 years ago, and I doubt that there is any system in existence that still uses it.  And I'm certain that no JVM uses the scheme.)

Comment: Thanks, I was confused by the "auto" storage used by a method. So the caller thread on its stack keeps the "*info*" he cares about the method.

Comment: Yep, it's really elegantly simple.  There is a dedicated register in the thread's register set that points at the "top" of the thread's stack.  When a new method is entered, the register is incremented by the size of the automatic storage area needed by the method.  On exit the register is decremented.  The method addresses the storage using that register as a "base register".  (Glossed over a few details, but that's the gist of it.)

Answer (score 0):

You'd have a bottleneck if one thread acquired a resource that others needed and held onto it for a long-running operation.  If that isn't the situation for your method, I don't see how you'll experience a bottle.

Is this a theoretical question, or are you observing behavior in a real application that's running more slowly than you think it should?

The best answer of all is to get some data and see.  Run a test and monitor it.  Be a scientist.

Comment: theoretical question -  but i'm going to code something like that and i wanted to make sure it's not completely stupid.